# Bertini's type theorems over imperfect fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, birational-geometry, minimal-model-program

Let $X$ be a projective variety over an imperfect (hence infinite and char(k)=p>0) field $k$. If the local rings of $X$ are all regular, then can we say that a general hyperplane section $H$ is also regular? If it helps, you can assume any combination of the following hypothesis on $k$:
$k$ contains a perfect (infinite) subfield $k_0$ or $k$ is a $F$-finite field or $k$ is a differentially finite over an (infinite) perfect subfield $k_0$ i.e., $\Omega_{k/k_0}$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $k_0$, or perhaps even the most geometric scenario that $k$ is a finite dimensional function field over an algebraically closed field $k_0$.

These type of results are very useful for studying varieties over imperfect fields; in particular studying families in positive characteristic over algebraically closed fields.

Note that there is a theorem of Seidenberg which says that if $X$ is a normal projective variety of dimension at least $2$ over an infinite field $k$, then a general hyperplane section $H$ of $X$ is irreducible and normal.

Comment: If $k$ is finitely generated over a perfect subfield $k_0$, then every regular $k$-variety $X$ is a localisation of a smooth $k_0$-variety $\mathcal X$. You could try to use Bertini theorems on $\mathcal X$ (if $k_0$ is infinite, or Poonen–Bertini if $k_0$ is finite) to prove statements on $X$.

Comment: Have you looked at Spreafico's [Axiomatic theory for transversality and Bertini type theorems](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s000130050213)? Spreafico works over arbitrary infinite fields, and shows that (in particular, see Cor. 4.3 and what follows) if $X$ is regular and $X \to \mathbf{P}^n$ induces separable field extensions of residue fields at *all* points, then the inverse image of a general hyperplane is regular. I think this condition is satisfied for closed embeddings.

Comment: @ R. van Dobben de Bruyn, this is what I had  in mind but would like to know if there is a more direct approach, since my filed $k$ not always a function field.

Comment: @Takumi Murayama, thank you so much for the reference, I was not aware of this article. I will take a look.

Comment: This is one of those questions where the answer could depend crucially on what you mean by "general" hyperplane, cf. this previous MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/230651/lefschetz-on-%C3%A9tale-fundamental-group-for-quasi-projective-varieties.

Comment: @user80473: if $k$ contains $k_0$, then $X$ is always going to be defined over some subfield $k_1 \subseteq k$ that is finitely generated over $k_0$. But maybe you run into problems base changing back to $k$, because regularity is not a geometric assumption.

Comment: @ R. van Dobben de Bruyn, good point. Thank you, I will think about it.

Comment: @Jason Starr, by general hyperplane $H$ I mean the following: Let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n_k$. Then there exists a Zarsiki dense open set $U\subset{\mathbb{P}^n_k}^\vee$ such that $H$ corresponds to a $k$-rational point  $[H]\in U(k)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I needed to know the answer to this myself, so here is a good reference:

> Hubert Flenner, Liam O’Carroll, and Wolfgang Vogel, *Joins and
>   intersections,* Springer Monographs in Mathematics, Springer-Verlag,
>   Berlin, 1999. MR [1724388](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1724388) DOI [10.1007/978-3-662-03817-8](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-03817-8)

The relevant results are the following:

**Theorem 3.4.10.** *Let $X$ be a variety over an infinite field $K$, and let $D$ be a Cartier divisor on $X$. Assume that $\Gamma \subseteq \lvert D \rvert$ is a finite-dimensional linear system that is not composed with a pencil and satisfies $\operatorname{codim} \operatorname{Bs}(\Gamma) \ge 2$. Then, a generic member of $\Gamma$ is irreducible.*

**Corollary 3.4.14.** *Let $X \subseteq \mathbf{P}^n_K$ be a projective scheme over an infinite field $K$ which is regular (resp. normal, reduced, satisfies $R_k$). Then, for a generic hyperplane $H \subseteq \mathbf{P}^n_K$, the intersection $X \cap H$ has the same property.*